# Injectivity of the spherical coordinates map

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

Define on $E = (0,\infty) \times (0,\pi) \times (0,2\pi)$ the spherical coordinates map:
$$
\psi: E \to \mathbb{R}^3, \ \ \psi(r,\theta,\phi) = (r \sin \theta \cos \phi, r \sin \theta \sin \phi, r \cos \theta). 
$$
I am trying to show that this map is injective. Intuitively, this is quite clear. We know that the vector $(x,y,z)$ coordinate in the 3-d space is uniquely determined by its length, $r$, its angle on the plane, $\theta$, and its angle in the $z$-direction, $\phi$. However, I don't know what is the best way to prove this formally. Basically we would like to show that if $\psi(r,\theta,\phi) = \psi(r',\theta',\phi')$, that is, 
$$
\begin{cases}
r \sin \theta \cos \phi = r' \sin \theta' \cos \phi' \\
r \sin \theta \sin \phi = r' \sin \theta' \sin \phi' \\
r \cos \theta = r' \cos \theta', 
\end{cases}
$$
then $(r,\theta,\phi) = (r',\theta',\phi')$. I have tried to decompose as two different functions, one on the unit sphere, and one to scale the length of the vector, but this does not work since the composition does not work out properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: Use the quotient of the first two equations to show $\phi = \phi'$. Then use the quotient of the second two equations to get $\theta = \theta'$. Then use the third equation for the last step.

Comment: If I'm correct this leads to a step where $\sin(\phi - \phi') = \sin(\phi' - \phi)$. Does it then follows that $\phi - \phi' = \phi' - \phi$? I don't see how this follows since $\phi - \phi', \phi' - \phi \in (-2\pi,2\pi)$.

Comment: I didn't get that. Could you explain how you got there?

Comment: Sure. But I probably did something wrong since I'm not good with trigonometry. By quotient of two equations, what exactly does that mean?

Comment: What I meant by quotient is: given equations $a = b$ and $c = d$, divide them so you conclude that $a/c = b/d$.

Comment: I see. Is it correct that I then get $\cos \phi \sin \phi' = \cos \phi' \sin \phi$? How to proceed to show that $\phi = \phi'$?

Comment: Yes, that is a valid conclusion. There are multiple ways to proceed from there. One way is to divide both sides of the equation by $\cos \phi \cos \phi'$ and recall that $\tan \phi = \sin \phi / \cos \phi$. Another is to use the formula for $\sin(\alpha - \beta)$.

Comment: @ theyaoster: Your idea doesn't work because if you take the quotient of the first two equations then you can get $ \tan(\phi)=\tan(\phi') $ which is also true for $ \phi=1 $ and $ \phi'=1+\pi $

Comment: I was using the principal value of $\arctan$ which is unique. You can easily reach a contradiction if you sub those values back into the original equations.